# Golang YouTube API V3 what is counted as a query (for quota purposes)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Using youtube Golang library ("google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3") I've made 14 request for video details on my account using this code:

```
// Retrieve resource for the authenticated user's channel
func  (y *Youtube) VideoDetails(id string) (*youtube.VideoListResponse, error) {
    call := y.service.Videos.List("Snippet,Status,RecordingDetails")
    call = call.Id(id)
    response, err := call.Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to connect %s", err)
    }
    return response, nil
}
```

where `y.service` is `*youtube.Service`

Yet according to the Quotas page (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas), I've made 163 request to youtube API. I wonder how do you count the quota calls? 
I thought the method above does only one call to youtube API e.g. `response, err := call.Do()` 
If not, could you please explain how did you count the requests?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you found this Quota Calculator on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost ?

Comment: I have not found it yet, thank you! This is super useful. 
Still according to this calculator I should have been charged for  `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status,recordingDetails`  which costs 7 per request, with 14 requests comes to 98, not 163 but at least this is somewhat closer...

Comment: Yes. this can only do approximate calculations, And not found how to get detail info.